# How can I align center (both vertical and horizontal) the triangle in the div#tag?

Tags: html, css

I am building a drawer with a tag.
When the tag is clicked, the `div#mySidenav` will be shown.
Here is my code:

```css
.container {
  background-color: #ff0000;
  /* red*/
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-grow: 1;
  height: 100%;
  /* 100% Full-height */
  position: fixed;
  /* Stay in place */
  top: 0;
  /* Stay at the top */
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

.sidenav {
  background-color: green;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  /* Disable horizontal scroll */
  width: 1px;
}

.sideNavTag {
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  width: 20px;
}

div#tag {
  align-content: center;
  border: 1px solid yellow;
  border-left: none;
  border-radius: 0px 5px 5px 0px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: flex;
  font-size: 20px;
  justify-content: center;
  left: 4.5px;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  position: relative;
  width: 20px;
}

div#a {
  border-bottom: 1px solid yellow;
  border-left: 1px solid yellow;
  border-radius: 0px 0px 0px 5px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: flex;
  height: calc(50% - 10px);
  margin: 0px;
  position: relative;
  top: 1px;
  width: 20px;
}

div#c {
  border-top: 1px solid yellow;
  border-left: 1px solid yellow;
  border-radius: 5px 0px 0px 0px;
  height: calc(50% - 10px);
  margin: 0px;
  position: relative;
  top: -1px;
  width: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav">1</div>
  <div class="sideNavTag">
    <div id="a"></div>
    <div id="tag">
      &#9654;
    </div>
    <div id="c"></div>
  </div>
  <div>3</div>
</div>
```

The `div#a`, `div#tag` and `div#c` are used to build the following layout:

[image]

How can I align center (both vertical and horizontal) the triangle in the yellow block (i.e. `div#tag)`?

I have used the `display: flex;` , `align-items: center;` and `justify-content: center;` CSS to align the triangle centre in the yellow block(i.e. `div#tag`). Unfortunately, it does not work.

How can I fix the problem?

Comment: hey, iwant to ask. in here i see the anchor tag has blocked the tag class movement. so, what will you do or fill in anchor tag. and i suggest you to fill all of the tag with the clearly fuctionality and we can solve it. thanks

Comment: In fact, that is not an anchor, this is a CSS class named "a". (.a not a)

Comment: what yellow you talking about? yellow borders?

Comment: Yes, I mean  the yellow bordered `div`.

Comment: yeah, it is a class. sorry my false @TheKNVB

Comment: Isn't the play button actually centered if you watch how the element align? The problem is that the play button got more margin bottom than top itself?

Comment: `The problem is that the play button got more margin bottom than top itself`
That is what I want to solve.

Comment: 'in the yellow block (i.e. div#tag)' - do you mean that #tag element because the arrow is centered horizontally on it - try giving div#tag a background color and you will see. I suspect that you want it centered between the left edge of the red and the yellow vertical line - could you clarify?

Comment: I want to align the play button centre both vertically and horizontally in the div#tag.

Comment: FYI there is no button yet, only divs. If you want to have a button which does something on click you should also use a `<button>` .